# FreeBSD: How to set Bash as the default shell

Tags: bash, shell, freebsd, defaults

I've used bash shell in all my Linuxes and in Mac OS X. I understand that tcsh is the default shell in FreeBSD. If I were to install bash, how would I  make it my default shell?

Comment: Should we distinguish between the root user and a non-root user?

Comment: I haven't voted on the question, but it might be worth noting whether you're aware of the chsh / chpass command or not.

Comment: As with most things, if you read the documentation in the Handbook, you'd have your answer.

Answer (score 8):

Changing one's login shell is covered by [The FreeBSD Handbook](https://docs.freebsd.org/en/books/handbook/), in the section called [Shells](https://docs.freebsd.org/en/books/handbook/basics/#shells).  It also points to a chapter called [Installing Applications: Packages and Ports](https://docs.freebsd.org/en/books/handbook/ports/) that will tell you what you need to know for installing `bash` (installing `bash` from a FreeBSD package would automatically update `/etc/shells`).

The steps involved, assuming an otherwise properly set up FreeBSD system, could probably be summarised into

```bash
sudo pkg install bash
chsh -s /usr/local/bin/bash
```

Answer (score 5):

There is also the [pw](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?pw(8)) utility.

```
shell> pw usermod <user> -s /usr/local/bin/bash
```